# Was Chodana ever expressed?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

Euthanatos in Mage: Ascension are death-mages who think that it is their duty to give Good Death to those whom they deem corrupted beyond repair. They have an elaborate set of traditions, rules and laws that describe their vocation. The most important one is Chodana, which is learned by heart by all Euthanatoi. Breaking the Chodana is a severe offense.

Has it ever been explicitly expressed?

Version does not matter to me too much. If there are different versions for 1st/2nd/Revised editions I'd like to know them all.

I am not looking for a general advice what the Chodana is about - I am looking for exact specific words that make up the Chodana as it would be recited. If there is no such expression, I would look for any expressions of Euthanatoic law that could form the basis of Chodana. Hence, a perfect answer would start with either "yes" or "no" and provide a word-for-word citation.

Answer (score 9):

### Tradition Book: Euthanatos (2002) "Chodona"

In the *Tradition Book: Euthanatos* (Revised, 2002) the Chodona (note variant spelling) is described in the glossary on p. 11 as:

> The Euthanatoi belief system and legal code, derived from the Eight-Spoked Wheel of the Law. The agreement that bound fate- and death-aspected mages into one Tradition.

Then on p. 27 of the same book there is a more comprehensive description of "the Eight Spoked Wheel of the Law or the Chakradharmasamhita, the Chodona".

The eight spokes in brief are:

1. Prevabhnava: recognition of the cycle of birth, death and rebirth
2. Hiranyagargha: fundamental unity of all that exists
3. Kala: decay part of the natural Cycle
4. Gopaya: the imperative to guard humankind and the world
5. Sadhana: the need for spriritual betterment and to resist temptations
6. Daya: the imperative not to close one's eyes to suffering
7. Tyaga: the avoidance of sensual pleasure and desires
8. Diksha: the need to experience death to have a new life

### Euthanatos (1997) "Chodana"

The earlier version of this book *Euthanatos* (1997) uses the "Chodana" spelling, but gives the vaguer glossary definition on p. 7 of:

> The code of ethics all Tradition Euthanatoi are *supposed* to follow.

Note that it does not directly link Chodana with the Eight Spoked Wheel, although the Wheel is described on p. 18 of this splat, with the same content as above. A direct connection between the Wheel and the Chodana is not made here either, although the Wheel is called a "code", and "our Law".